# How to update with animation a Pie Chart?

Tags: jquery, jinja2, chart.js

I can't animate my **Pie Chart** when clicking update so a new chart with a new content comes in, the content is updating but the chart remains as it was , i want to update it and at the same time the chart should showing with new lines and points.

Here is my code:

```
<canvas id="chart-area-service_hours"></canvas>

<button class="button btn btn-md btn-block btn-default" id="update-
statistic" style="width: 50%;margin: 0 auto;">Обнавить</button>

var randomHours = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 12);
};

var service_hours = {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
                {% for service in current_user.services %}
                    [
                        randomHours(),
                    ],
                {% endfor %}

            ],
            backgroundColor: [
                {% for service in current_user.services %}
                    '#00FFFF',
                    window.chartColors.purple,
                    '#ff9900',
                    window.chartColors.grey,
                    window.chartColors.brown,
                    // window.chartColors.green,
                    // window.chartColors.yellow,
                    // window.chartColors.purple,
                {% endfor %}
            ],
            label: 'Распределение рабочих часов по услугам'
        }],
        labels: [
            {% for service in current_user.services %} 
                "{{service.title}}",
            {% endfor %}
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,

    }
};

    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area-service_hours").getContext("2d");
    window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, service_hours);

document.getElementById('update-statistic').addEventListener('click', function() {
    all_brnoi_line.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
        dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
            return randomScalingFactor();
        });
    });
    $("#chart-area-1").hide().html('<canvas id="chart-area-1" class="all-broni">').fadeIn('fast');
    window.myPie.update();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add Chart.js Version: 1.0.2 form [Here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases) than it will work.

Html Code:

```
<canvas id="pieChart" style="height: 325px; width: 550px !important; margin-left:17%; margin-top:3%;"></canvas>
```

JQuery Code:

```
 var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
 var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
 var PieData = [ {
         value: '7',
         color: "#F56954",
         highlight: "#F56954",
         label: "abc"
     },
           {
               value: '5',
               color: "#605CA8",
               highlight: "#605CA8",
               label: "xyz"
           },
            {
                value: '9',
                color: "#37495F",
                highlight: "#37495F",
                label: "asdf"
            },
             {
                 value: '4',
                 color: "#2B908F",
                 highlight: "#2B908F",
                 label: "lkh"
             }];
 var pieOptions = {
            //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
            segmentShowStroke: true,
            //String - The colour of each segment stroke
            segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
            //Number - The width of each segment stroke
            segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
            //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
            percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts
            //Number - Amount of animation steps
            animationSteps: 100,
            //String - Animation easing effect
            animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
            //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
            animateRotate: true,
            //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
            animateScale: false,
            //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
            responsive: true,
            // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            //String - A legend template
            legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
        };
        //Create pie or douhnut chart
        // You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
        pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
```

hope helps.

Comment: Thanks for your interests, i'll give it a try .

Comment: The same thing content is changing and the chart toggling as it reloaded but in the console it says :
pieChart.Doughnut is not a function

Comment: you need to add   Chart.js  Version: 1.0.2 than it will work.

Comment: download it from [Here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.5.0) . Thanks and include it in project

Comment: do you add the chart.js file if reference?

Comment: yes, i included it inside my template where it should be !

Comment: right click on .Doughnut() method and go to defination. if it is going in chart.js than it means file is included right.

Comment: The problem is that, all my charts will not work with chart 1.0.2 , i made a new html file to try if it will work , and it worked :), don't know what to do with the rest !!

Comment: If i included Chart.js 1.0.2 all my other charts disappears !

Comment: you can try the latest version with this hope it will work and compatible with the rest.

Comment: which charts you are using?

Comment: my solution works for it. now you have to make it compatible with all rest charts.

Comment: Am using Chart.bundle.js  v2.5.0 !!

Comment: i try this also. its working , you have to find the actual problem with the rest.

Comment: if my answer work in separate file, it means my solution is acceptable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with the latest version of `Chart.js`.

If you want to update your chart with animation, its not enough to add the data and to update them as i it shown above in my code, you must add the **addEventListener** first then again to create a **new Chart** by which the effect happens :

```
document.getElementById('update-statistic').addEventListener('click', function() {
    all_brnoi_line.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
        dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
            return randomScalingFactor();
        });
    });
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area-1").getContext("2d");
    var pieChart = new Chart(ctx, all_brnoi_line);
    var PieData = [{
        labels: MONTHS,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Эффективные - брони",
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor()
            ],
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
            borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
            fill: false,
            borderDash: [5, 5],
            pointRadius: 15,
            pointHoverRadius: 10,
        }, {
            label: "Неэффективные - брони",
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor()
            ],
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
            borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
            fill: false,
            borderDash: [5, 5],
            pointRadius: [2, 4, 6, 18, 0, 12, 20],
        }, {
            label: "Спорные - брони",
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor()
            ],
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.purple,
            borderColor: window.chartColors.purple,
            fill: false,
            pointHoverRadius: 20,
            borderDash: [5, 5],
            pointRadius: [2, 4, 6, 18, 0, 12, 20],
        }, {
            label: "Отменённые - брони",
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor(), 
                randomScalingFactor()
            ],
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.yellow,
            borderColor: window.chartColors.yellow,
            fill: false,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            borderDash: [5, 5],
            pointRadius: [2, 4, 6, 18, 0, 12, 20],
        }]
    }

    ];
    window.myPie.update();
});
```